# Stylus: how to recompile upon saving an import file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, stylus

I'm using Compile Hero in VS Code to watch my Stylus files. Problem: Saving a `.styl` to be imported by the main `.styl` does not recompile the `.css` (unlike with Live Sass Compiler).

Can VS Code be set up so that I can preview the output `.css` while editing-and-saving each non-main import `.styl` without performing an extra save on the (unedited) main `.styl`?